# When should Java futures be propagated vs joining them immediately?

Tags: java, asynchronous, future, completable-future

In a language like Javascript once a function is `async` its caller also has to be marked as `async` so it's very straightforward. In Java however if an API method `x()` returns a `CompletableFuture` we have the choice of either joining it immediately thus blocking or have the caller `y()` return `CompletableFuture` as well.

If `x()` method is called multiple times in a loop then it's a clear advantage not to join it immediately so that multiple `x()` calls are performed concurrently.

However, if I have just one call to `x()` and then I need to do something with its result then it seems that there's no advantage not to join it immediately. Am I missing something? Are there any advantages to keep propagating `CompletableFuture`s along the call stack in this case?

Comment: You can also add a continuation with `.thenAccept` that will be executed once the value is available. No need to "wait" for the future.

Comment: You wait for completion ("join") when you need the result.  There's generally no point in waiting before that.  If you have a method whose contract says it returns a future, why would you force a wait before return?

Comment: Does `x()` know whether the caller will call it in a loop or just a single time with the intend to do something with its result immediately? The obvious conclusion should be, since a method does not know the caller’s intent, a method should return the future (when this option exists) and let the caller decide whether to join or not.

Comment: I suppose besides what everyone's already saying, isn't it simpler to write 1 codepath that works just as efficiently whether 1 iteration or many? Rather than a special handling for the case of 1.

Comment: @AndrewCheong it totally makes sense what you're saying, but the overhead of having a method which returns a `CompletableFuture` is to have its callers also return `CompletableFuture` in order to really reap the benefits of async programming, which can be tedious.

Comment: You’re referring to the [What Color is Your Function?](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) problem. However, when returning a `CompletableFuture` in Java, you’re not forcing the caller to return a `CompletableFuture` too. They still can `join()`. Only when they want to retain async support, they have to, but then, there’s no alternative anyway. Only when virtual threads aka Loom finally arrive in Java, you don’t have to worry about such things anymore (except for a few corner cases, perhaps).